# Why does applying the PPT criterion to the Werner state result in an inequality?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

The so called partial transpose criterion (PPT), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion, tells us that is the partial transpose of a density matrix has a negative eigenvalue, the state is entangled.

Ok, that's straightforward.
But then why is this a inequality in the example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion#Example, a compund inequality
[image]

the $p>1/3$ part of the inequality is clear.

But the $p\leq 1$ is not.
It amounts to saying (checked in mathematica) the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has $|\lambda|<1/2$ and that is not straightforward to me.

Comment: Posting images of math or text is very strongly discouraged on the site.  Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $p<1$ is a constraint that comes from making sure $\rho$ is actually a kosher density matrix.

A density matrix $\rho = \sum_{j} p_{j} | \psi^{-}\rangle \langle \psi^{-} |$ needs to have $p_j$ all add up to 1 and also each be non-negative. In your case the state has the form
$$
\rho = p | \Psi^{-}\rangle \langle \Psi^{-} | + (1-p) I/4
$$
where obviously $I/4$ is a projection, and so we need $p_1:=p$ and $p_2 = 1-p$. We have $p_1 + p_2 = 1$ obviously, but making sure $p_j \geq 0$ implies that we need $p\leq 1$.

Something else that you can check is that the above makes the purity well-defined as well: calculating $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho^2] = \frac{1}{4}( 1 + 3 p^2 )$. Since the purity must be bounded between $1/4$ and $1$ here you find that you need $0 \leq p \leq 1$ for things to make sense.

This means your entanglement constraint tightens the bound from $0 \leq p \leq 1$ to $1/3< p \leq 1$